# Adding textangular to a seed with angular <1.2 updated to 1.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, bower

Hi I am starting a project based on [this](https://github.com/btford/angular-express-blog) seed. Problem is I want to include the textAngular directive in my app, so I used bower to fetch the necessary deppendencies: textangular, Angular 1.2 and angular-route.
I did some minor changes to the code to to read in the new angular version from the bower folders. But angular seems to be failing : `uncaught object : angular.js line 78`.

Here is an example of my code so far:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components')); //Added this line in the express server js.
```

Added this to index.jade  so that angular from the bower folder is used, as well as textangular:

```
script(src='/angular/angular.js')
script(src='/angular-route/angular-route.js')
script(src='/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js')
script(src='/textAngular/dist/textAngular.min.js')
script(src='js/app.js')
script(src='js/services.js')
script(src='js/controllers.js')
script(src='js/filters.js')
script(src='js/directives.js')
```

Any ideas why it is not working? i tried reversing the order of angular and angular-route in the jade script tags above, but that was not it.

Comment: did you update the dependency injections in the angular module?

Comment: Yes i added 'textAngular' to the module in the injection (forgot to mention it above)

Comment: in older versions of angular `$route` was in core. If using more current versions need to inject it as dependency also